# Is there a way to store the sending emails if the server goes offline?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, smtp

I'm working on my PHP to send the list of emails. What happens is when I am sending each emails and if the server goes offline, would the server store the list of emails that I am trying to send or the data would be lost?

e.g: I send 10 emails and 4 of them would not be send because the server get shutdown, so would 4 of them store on the server or it would be lost?

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

if (isset($_POST['to']))
{
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $from_sender = explode('<', $from);
    $from_address = $from_sender[1];
    $from_address = str_replace('>', '', $from_address);
    $domain = explode('@', $from_address);
    $from_domain = '@' . $domain[1];
    $to_email = $_POST['to'];
    $total_emails = count($to_email);
    
    foreach ($to_email as $to)
    {
        $messageID = sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
            base_convert($microtime, 16, 36),
            base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
            'domain.com');
        $message_id = getMessageid(isset($message_id));
        
        //SMTP details...
        $host = "smtp.domain.com";
        $username = 'ssafsaf@domain.com';
        $password = 'password';
        $port = '587';
        $crlf = "\r\n";
        //$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
        $mime = new Mail_mime("\r\n");
        $body = $html;

        $mime->setTXTBody($text);
        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

        $mime_params = array(
            'text_encoding' => '7bit',
            'text_charset'  => '"UTF-8"',
            'html_charset'  => '"UTF-8"',
            'head_charset'  => '"UTF-8"'
        );

         // always call these methods in this order
        $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);


        $smtp_params = array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true, // Note 1
            //'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password);
        
        
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtp_params);
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail))
        {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        }
        else 
        {
            echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");
        }

        if (($total_emails) > 1) {
            sleep(20);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cS', function(e) {

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var from = $('.nT').text() + '<' + $('.eA').text() + '>';
    var subject = $('#compose_subject').val();
    var message = $('#compose_message').html();
    var current_link = window.location.href;
    var compose_reciept = '';
    var compose_bcc_reciept = '';
    var compose_cc_reciept = '';
    var mailfolder = '';
    var encryption = '';
    var search_text = '';
    var attachments = [];

    if ($('#bcc').find('.md-chip').length > 0) {
    

        $('#bcc').find('.md-chip').each (function () {
            full_name = $(this).find('span').text();
            email = $(this).attr('data-hovercard-email');

            if (bcc_reciept == '') {
                compose_bcc_reciept = full_name + ' <' + email + '>';
            }
            else if (bcc_reciept != '') {
                compose_bcc_reciept += ' ' + full_name + ' <' + email + '>';
            }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        type: 'POST',

        data : {
            from: from,
            to: compose_reciept,
            bcc: compose_bcc_reciept,
            cc: compose_cc_reciept,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            attachments: attachments
        },
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(result) {
        }
        });
    }
});
```

What is the best way to store the emails if the server goes offline?

Do I have to store the list of emails using json or what?

Comment: If the "server" is powered-off, then no, that "server" will not queue emails.    If your code does not error when sending to the email server but that email server can't send the email on to the next stage for whatever reason (eg the lan is working, but external internet is not ("offline")) then the email server *will\** store emails until it can send them on (\*should if it's a proper email server).  If your code can't connect to the email server, then it will need to store the email until it can.

Comment: @freedomn-m Oh thank you very much for this as this is very clear for me. I have got few questions. When my server is online and I send the emails, will the server queue my emails so it will not get lost if the server goes offline?  When the software send the email, are they going to delete each of the email that have already been on the queue list? If I use the hourly sending limit, will it only allow me to send no more than 5,000 emails in per hour?

Comment: All those questions depend on which software your server is running

Comment: @freedomn-m The email server software that i am running is called exim and postfix.

Comment: You have absolutely no hope of setting up an email server to send 5000 per hour. If you do more than 150 per DAY to gmail you will already be on their spam radar and quickly blocked. Servers that have just spawned are initially limited to 10-20 emails per day to say gmail. GMX, Hotmail, MSN, and Outlook are much stricter. If you want to send bulk emails, use a bulk email service instead such as alibabacloud, sendingblue or mailchimp.

Comment: @AndyGee I am renting a email server and I can modify the sending limit. Where does it say that i can send 10 - 20 emails per day to gmail? It havent say anything on google?